# webrtc: video stream not playing in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, vp8

I have pre-recorded opus and vp8 files. In a webrtc call I am trying to stream audio / video to chrome.

While audio is played in chrome, but it fails to show video.

I read from google search that first video frame I need to send as i-frame. I am bit new to video stuff. Can somebody help me to learn how to send a i-frame in case of video.

Can there be other potential issues, why chrome does not like video frames. Please note that ICE and Dtls handshake goes well.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Both the JS and your HTML element

Comment: I have a C based application. After signalling done, I am sending video packets to Chrome, and also receiving video packets from Chrome. Chrome not playing these video packets. What could be the possible reason(s).

Comment: How does your implementation look like? Do you have `autoplay` attribute at the video element? Please provide some code

Comment: I have a mkv file containing h264 encoded packets. I read those h264 encoded packets from mkv file and use as payload for RTP packet. Then I send those RTP packets to Chrome. In other side, it is a third party webrtc client running in a Chrome. Signalling is successful. Chrome is playing the audio packets I send, but video packets it is not playing.

Comment: Are you sure the WebRTC client is working? Because Chrome is sending and receiving video packets, it sounds like a problem with the client. And to debug what the actual problem is, it would be great to see the client code

Comment: I do not have client code with me. I have my C code only. Now if you can hep me how to debug, why chrome is not playing my video packets, it will be a great help.